# Книга или книжка?

Tags: словообразование, стилистика, недопустимая-метка

Из предыдущего вытек следующий вопрос.
У меня была знакомая, которая считала слово "книжка" оскорбительным для книги. А вообще, является ли слово "книжка" уменьшительным или пренебрежительным? Или "книга" и "книжка" — равноправные и равнозначные слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Книжка, конечно, не равноправно книге. У него есть и собственное значение (медицинская книжка, например), но по отношению к книге - это уменьшительное. Только почему "пренебрежительное"?!

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле я хочу продолжить ряд, чтобы проиллюстрировать разницу.

1. Книга - просто рядовая книга. Может быть большая, может быть не очень. Отношение нейтральное.
2. Книжка - маленькая книга. Или нечто специализированное (медицинская книжка). Отношение - нейтральное.
3. Книжечка - тоже маленькая книга, но отношение уже получается какое-то детско-умилительное.
4. Книжонка - а вот это именно то, что просили - маленькая книга, к которой относятся с пренебрежением.
5. Книженция - уничижительное
6. Книжище - боооольшая книга

Хочу обратить внимание на различность использованных суффиксов

Comment: Почему "книженция" - уничижительное? Скорее юмористическое.

Comment: Может быть.

Comment: А разве книжища пишется не с окончанием "а"? Помнится, такое правило касается слов женского рода с увеличительным суффиксом "-ищ-"

Comment: Хороший вопрос!
Но трудно не согласиться, что в последнее время наметилась тенденция произносить "увеличительные" слова женского рода на -ща с явным "ще", на слух они вполне себе различимы. Более того, они в реи ставновzтся среднего рода: "мой книжище", "моё квартирище", и даже "моё дочище!"  
Причем, насколько могу судить, более всего этому подвержены неодушевленные существительные в исходном виде принадлежащие к первому (женскому) склонению.